# A commerce fees rule works fine, but is giving the warnings in the log

Tags: commerce

I've enabled the Commerce Fees module and added a rule with the following details:

```
{ "rules_setup_fee" : {
    "LABEL" : "Setup Fee",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "Commerce License Billing" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "commerce_fees" ],
    "ON" : { "commerce_fees_order" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "text_matches" : {
          "text" : [ "commerce-order:commerce-line-items:0:line-item-label" ],
          "match" : "book"
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "commerce_fees_apply" : {
          "entity" : [ "commerce-order" ],
          "fee" : "setup_fee",
          "amount" : "999",
          "currency_code" : "USD"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

which correctly adds $9.99 setup fee to a shopping cart when customer selects any product which has the "book" string in its title (or SKU which we try to keep the same). So the whole thing serves its purpose just fine, however unfortunately it also leaves the following traces in the logs:

> Unable to evaluate condition text_matches. Unable to get the data
>   value for the variable or parameter text. Error: Unable to get the
>   data property line_item_label as the parent data structure is not set.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a `data_exists` to ensure that the delta/label you're trying to access actually exists. It looks like `line-item-label` is a custom property.

Comment: Nick, I am not sure if I should post this question separately, but it's relevant. The above rule works fine now without giving any errors, however the log is full of "Reacting on event Apply a fee to a given order." messages. Seems like the rule is invoked even if nobody is going to order page, is it normal or should I re-write my rule?

Comment: What version of commerce are you using?

Comment: It shows Commerce 7.x-1.11 in the modules page.

Comment: Without looking at the code, it's hard to say, but as long as there are no errors, it sounds like debugging is just turned on and adding stuff to the log. The rules will re-apply on order refresh which can happen on every page load.

Comment: O yea, I enabled debug logs on admin/config/workflow/rules/settings, but is it really normal that this particular rule is invoked on every page load? The reason I am worried is that other rules are invoked only when needed.

Comment: Do you have discounts enabled? Discounts operates in the same way but other systems like shipping don't work in the same manner. It might not be the best way to do things, but it is pretty normal as far as commerce goes.

Comment: No, only the Commerce Fees with the above rule, nothing else with regard fees/prices.

Comment: Nick, I believe without adding some kind of condition the above rule is adding performance issues on every page visit: `Rules debug information:
" Reacting on event Apply a fee to a given order.
0 ms Reacting on event Apply a fee to a given order.
3.138 ms Evaluating conditions of rule Setup Fee. [edit]
3.583 ms The condition data_is_empty evaluated to TRUE [edit]
3.59 ms AND evaluated to FALSE.
3.605 ms Finished reacting on event Apply a fee to a given order.`